# Facebook sees same keyhashes as being different

Tags: android, facebook

Recently I've launched my 1st Android app which uses Facebook login. The login worked perfectly until I made the last update. Now, when I try to login, I get the message

> The keyhash ABC does not match any stored hashes

But, if I go to My Developer Page > My App, the stored key hash is **EXACTLY THE SAME** as the one prompted in the error. I can tell you that it's not the display issue, where Facebook displays underscore instead of slash.
Is there anybody that knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there was an issue reported as [bug with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/827156350736265/). If you are still experiencing this issue, I recommend that you add your repro steps in a comment to the bug report. Make sure that you comment the exact error message as well as your app ID.

You should also verify that your key-hash extraction command is correct. Since typically this command is a really a series of piped commands, try executing the 1st step of the pipeline separately, to check if it doesn't print errors. Next, try piping the output through the 2nd stage only. Check for errors again, before oyou continue to the next step.